# Combine multiple Wordpress pages to 1 page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I am using a custom theme which uses Custom Page Templates for creating pages, but the page templates don't allow to add more content or edit the pages with Gutenburg or a page builder (basically it creates a 1 section page).

So I'm also Elementor Page Builder to create some pages which contains sections that I want to add to my homepage. I need to combine all these elementor pages and the custom pages made using theme templates, so that I can show them as sections of my Home Page.

Is there a way to do that by using a plugin or any development techniques, like creating a custom page template or editing the child theme?

Here's the theme that I'm using currently:

https://themeforest.net/item/ashade-photography-wordpress-theme/25620022?gclid=CjwKCAiAmrOBBhA0EiwArn3mfAV0YHIfYMwantDXLMFndFol9CM-lZmucHpPk7VkfpN13-Pz_Kkw1BoCmoYQAvD_BwE

Here are the pages I'm trying to combine:

1. http://navana.com/home-with-video/
2. http://navana.com/achievements/
3. http://navana.com/activities/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Template and copy all three Tempplates in to this new page template as you like. ( With an Editor like Notepad++)

Therefore it would be good to create a Childtheme, so your template will be not overwritten by updates.